# PHP XML Parser Question

Tags: php, xml, regex

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Players of Liverpool F.C." />
<meta name="keywords" content="liverpool, players of liverpool" />
<title>Players of Liverpool F.C.</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liverpool_F.C.');
$domxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($domxpath->query('//span[@id="Players"]/../following-sibling::table[1]//span[@class="fn"]') as $a)
{echo
"
<p>$a->textContent</p>
";
};
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Hello, how can I parse an XML that includes all of the `$a->textContent` with a tag like `<player></player>`?

Comment: You wan to extract the players list into your own xml document? Or just scrape the players into this page you've pasted above?

Answer (score 1):

You had misspelled the address for the wikipedia-article. Furthermore, you should put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

as the beginning at generally make your xml welformed:

```
<?php 
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Liverpool_fc');
$domxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n";
echo "\t<players>\n";
foreach ($domxpath->query('//span[@id="Players"]/../following-sibling::table[1]//span[@class="fn"]') as $a)
{
    echo "\t\t<player>$a->textContent</player>\n";
};
echo "\t</players>";
?>
```

This output a nice xml-list of players:

http://gregersboye.dk/test.php

(you might need to look at the sourcecode, firefox doesn't display it nice as is)